# Wordpress - wp-admin showing blank

Tags: wordpress

Every part of my web site is working fine after I moved it from one hosting to another. The problem I have now is that I can't access wp-admin.

I now get the following error:

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/everd1/public_html/precision/wp-content/themes/Avada/Avada/admin/functions/functions.options.php:1) in /home/everd1/public_html/precision/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1121
```

So far I've tried:

- Removing trailing white space before and after functions.php and pluggable.php
- Increasing the allowed memory size on the .htaccess file
- Creating a php.ini within the wp-admin folder with the following `memory_limit = 64M ;`
- Renamed the plugins folder to plugins-removed

Still no joy, anything I can do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The warning that you have posted shows the exact error and the place that it is happening.

It looks like something within the Avada theme has broken when you were transfering it and it has since messed up the headers being sent through.

Only 1 set of headers can be sent to the client otherwise it cannot be handled and therefore throws an error.

I would recommend going to the theme creators ([click here](http://theme-fusion.com/)) and putting in a support ticket. One of their support team should be able to fix the problem that you are having.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if some file of your Wordpress copy contains UTF-8 with BOM files and **convert it to UTF-8 without BOM.**

You can try this php script to make it faster : https://github.com/emrahgunduz/BomCleaner

*Be sure to make a backup before running it.*